# python - importing module from within a module

Tags: python, file, python-import, import-module

I have this file `pluralizer.py` containing functions and a class which use the `re` module:

```
from re import *

def pluralize(noun, funcs):
     for matches_rule, apply_rule in funcs:
         if matches_rule(noun):
             return apply_rule(noun)
     raise ValueError("no matching rule for {0}".format(noun))


def build_match_and_apply_functions(pattern, search, replace):
     def matches_rule(word):
         return re.search(pattern, word)
     def apply_rule(word):
         return re.sub(search, replace, word)
     return (matches_rule, apply_rule)


class LazyRules:
     rules_filename = 'rules.txt' #a class variable - shared across all instances of the LazyRules class
     def __init__(self):
         self.pattern_file = open(self.rules_filename, encoding="utf-8")
         self.cache=[]
     def __iter__(self):
         self.cache_index=0
         return self #returning self signals that this class defines a __next__ method
     def __next__(self):
         self.cache_index += 1
         if len(self.cache) >= self.cache_index:
             return self.cache[self.cache_index-1]
         if self.pattern_file.closed:
             raise StopIteration
         line = self.pattern_file.readline()
         if not line: #if there's a line to read, it will not be an empty string (even if new row, it will be "\n")
             self.pattern_file.close()
             raise StopIteration
         pattern,search,replace= line.split(None,3)
         funcs = build_match_and_apply_functions(pattern,search,replace)
         self.cache.append(funcs) # before returning the match&apply functions, we save them in the list self.cache
         return funcs
```

There's also the data file `rules.txt`:

```
[sxz]$               $    es
[^aeioudgkprt]h$     $    es
[^aeiou]y$          y$    ies
$                    $    s
```

The way it's supposed to work is:

```
import pluralizer
funcs = pluralizer.LazyRules()
p = pluralizer.pluralize("baby", funcs)
```

from which the expected output is `"babies"`, but I get:

```
NameError: name 're' is not defined
```

Placing `import re` inside `pluralize` function didn't work either. How come the `re` module 'refuses' to import? I searched old questions but didn't find an answer, sorry if I overlooked it.  Thanks!

P.S. Code is from ['Dive Into Python 3' by Mark Pilgrim](http://www.diveintopython3.net/iterators.html)

Comment: try `import re` instead of `from re import *`, as the latter will import everything from `re` into the current namespace, not into `re.<methods>`

Comment: I tried that as well, but unfortunately that gave me the same error. :(

Comment: You place `import re` at the start of `pluralizer.py`, not into the `pluralize` function.

Comment: That's what I did, but it's still 'not defined'. I'm totally puzzled...

Comment: post the entire stack trace, (including file locations)

Answer (score 0):

works for me as follows, before running it, I make sure to change the working directory within the python shell

```
import os
os.chdir('whatever your working directory and files are')
```

The code in my 'lazyrules.py' file looks like

```
import re
def build_match_and_apply_functions(pattern, search, replace):
    def matches_rule(word):
        return re.search(pattern, word)
    def apply_rule(word):
        return re.sub(search, replace, word)
    return (matches_rule, apply_rule)

def plural(noun, funcs):
    for matches_rule, apply_rule in funcs:
        if matches_rule(noun):
            return apply_rule(noun)
    raise ValueError('no matching rule for {0}'.format(noun))

class LazyRules:
    rules_filename = 'plural6-rules.txt'

    def __init__(self):
        self.pattern_file = open(self.rules_filename, encoding='utf-8')
        self.cache = []

    def __iter__(self):
        self.cache_index = 0
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        self.cache_index += 1
        if len(self.cache) >= self.cache_index:
            return self.cache[self.cache_index - 1]

        if self.pattern_file.closed:
            raise StopIteration

        line = self.pattern_file.readline()
        if not line:
            self.pattern_file.close()
            raise StopIteration

        pattern, search, replace = line.split(None, 3)
        funcs = build_match_and_apply_functions(pattern, search, replace)
        self.cache.append(funcs)
        return funcs

rules = LazyRules()
```